# How do we nominate other users as moderators?

Tags: support, election

I understand that the 2019 Moderator Election is currently in the nomination phase, but the only information I found related to nominating relates to self-nomination.

How do we nominate *other* users as moderators?

Comment: I believe, since moderating is entirely volunteer work, the user would need to willingly nominate themselves. You're free to jump into a chatroom and ping the person to nominate.

Comment: I was hoping to anonymously nominate some users I felt were suitable to become moderators, and because the election page said "Nominations are not binding" I assumed those nominated users could either accept or withdraw the nomination based on their personal preferences and situations. Pinging them would remove the anonomyity aspect.  Is there really no other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People can only nominate themselves.

1. You cannot assume that someone else is willing to invest a lot of time for that.
2. And you really don't want to "spam" someone with a nomination who then has to opt out.
3. The worst case would be that someone is actually elected as a moderator without knowing about it. They might be on vacation or absent for another reason. Then we'd have a moderator who doesn't moderate – which is worse than having no one elected.

Comment: Related meta-answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247356/322985

Comment: Please be patient with me, I don't mean to argue. Just to get clarification: nomination is just the first phase, isn't it? They would still have to go through the primary and election phases. So if someone is nominated and they don't accept the nomination then it should end there, right? Because if they opt-out of the nomination they wouldn't be bumped to the next phase and made moderators without their knowledge.

Comment: Furthermore, even if they were bumped up to the primary phase without their knowledge, how can they be elected if they were absent long enough to miss out on answering the moderator questions and participating in the remaining phases? I feel like there is a confusion between nominated/elected status. I think of nomination as a suggestion or proposal, a way of saying: how about this person for moderator? It does not mean they will be a moderator.

Comment: The 2nd part to the "Nominations are not binding" text states "nominees may withdraw at their discretion at any point during the nomination phase" which means, if **they do not withdraw** their nomination will continue onto the next phase". It's not an acceptance, it's a manually opt-in and manually opt-out situation. This is not something that we, as mods of WordPress Stackexchange, control but is the same election process on all Stackexchange websites controlled by SE employees. You may always propose a change to the election process on [Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).